# How do I include a SQL count with condition as a subquery

Tags: sql, debugging, subquery, aggregate-functions

I've written this query:

```
select a_patient.pID,
       pname,
       ( select count(*)
           from app
          where staffID = 1234
            and app.staffID = a_patient.staffID
       )
  from app,
       a_patient
 where app.pID = a_patient.pID 
 order
    by surname
;
```

The problem is, the subquery is returning the count of *all* records, rather than the count of just those records where `staffID = 1234`.

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: I think you have to use the correct aliases

Comment: It shouldn't do that. In fact this query should return all apps/patient combinations and return `0` as a count for all staffs but 1234. Can you confirm that?

Comment: Hi Amirreza, I am using Oracle

Comment: Hi Alexander, yes I think I am using the correct aliases but maybe I should take out the cross reference in the count section and only include the staffID criteria? because as Golez rightly points out, the count is returned as zero with the above.

Answer (score 0):

Use the primary key in the count rather than the wildcard, and move the subquery to the WHERE clause, as in this example:

```
SELECT U.Id as [User Link], U.Reputation
FROM Users U
WHERE
(SELECT Count(V.Id) AS [FAVORITES] FROM Votes V, VoteTypes Vt WHERE Vt.Id = V.VoteTypeId AND U.Id = V.UserId AND Vt.Id = 5) > 1000
ORDER BY U.Reputation DESC
```

**References**

- [Users with the most Favorites](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/154583/users-with-the-most-favorites)